# Minimum Kernel configuration to use Azure accelerated networking

Tags: linux, azure, configuration, kernel

I am trying to add Azure accelerated networking support to a custom built Linux kernel. I enabled all the mellanox drivers, support for VFIO, infiniband drivers, vsock support and all of the hyperv drivers.

When I enable accelerated networking on my NIC using azure cli, the lspci output shows that the NIC is Mellanox NIC. But when I run "ethtool -S  | grep vf_", I get the following output

vf_rx_packets: 0
vf_rx_bytes: 0
vf_tx_packets: 0
vf_tx_bytes: 0
vf_tx_dropped: 0

This makes me feel that accelerated networking is not really working. The Linux I am working on is a custom minimal build of Debian 9.5. The kernel I am trying to build is 4.19.56. We build our own kernel so please don't ask to use the azure linux kernel from backports.

What I need is something as follows. Lets say I did the following:
1) Downloaded 4.19.56 kernel from Kernel.org
2) ran "make defconfig"
3) ran make
4) ran make modules

Now what I need is the list of kernel options that I need to enable for accelerated networking. Something like you did "make defconfig", saved your config somewhere, then ran "make menuconfig" and selected options needed for accelerated networking. Now I need the diff of these two configurations that you get by running scripts/diffconfig script or the list of options that one has to enable after going into menuconfig.

Please feel free to comment if you need more information.

PS: I have already gone through all the documentation microsoft have for accelerated networking and also have taken a look in there accelerated networking git repository. I failed to find minimum list of options needed anywhere.

Adding output of 
lspci:

```
root@localhost:/var/www# lspci
0000:00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 440BX/ZX/DX - 82443BX/ZX/DX Host bridge (AGP disabled) (rev 03)
0000:00:07.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 ISA (rev 01)
0000:00:07.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 IDE (rev 01)
0000:00:07.3 Bridge: Intel Corporation 82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 ACPI (rev 02)
0000:00:08.0 VGA compatible controller: Microsoft Corporation Hyper-V virtual VGA
8d87:00:02.0 Ethernet controller: Mellanox Technologies MT27500 Family [ConnectX-3 Virtual Function]
```

Output of ip link show:

```
root@localhost:/var/www# ip link show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: ifb0: <BROADCAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT qlen 32
    link/ether 3a:1c:d6:ba:bd:a1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: ifb1: <BROADCAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT qlen 32
    link/ether b6:5b:61:57:61:73 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: teql0: <NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT qlen 100
    link/void
5: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0d:3a:54:ed:da brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master eth0 state DOWN mode DEFAULT qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0d:3a:54:ed:da brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

output of "ethtool -S eth0 | grep vf_":

```
root@localhost:/var/www# ethtool -S eth0 | grep vf_
vf_rx_packets: 0
vf_rx_bytes: 0
vf_tx_packets: 0
vf_tx_bytes: 0
vf_tx_dropped: 0
cpu0_vf_rx_packets: 0
cpu0_vf_rx_bytes: 0
cpu0_vf_tx_packets: 0
cpu0_vf_tx_bytes: 0
cpu1_vf_rx_packets: 0
cpu1_vf_rx_bytes: 0
cpu1_vf_tx_packets: 0
cpu1_vf_tx_bytes: 0
cpu2_vf_rx_packets: 0
cpu2_vf_rx_bytes: 0
cpu2_vf_tx_packets: 0
cpu2_vf_tx_bytes: 0
cpu3_vf_rx_packets: 0
cpu3_vf_rx_bytes: 0
cpu3_vf_tx_packets: 0
cpu3_vf_tx_bytes: 0
```

output from dmesg | grep "Data path switched"

```
root@localhost:/var/www# dmesg | grep "Data path switched"
hv_netvsc 000d3a54-edda-000d-3a54-edda000d3a54 eth0: Data path switched to VF: eth1
hv_netvsc 000d3a54-edda-000d-3a54-edda000d3a54 eth0: Data path switched from VF: eth1
```

Thanks & Regards

Comment: I tried diffing against the default debian backport kernel. There were hundreds of changes to support different sort of sensors, kernel live patching and other stuff. Its hard to understand from there whats really needed for azure and what was just enabled for general support of sensors and other features in the Linux kernel that we don't use.

Comment: Added the output of lspci and ip link show commands

Comment: Added the output here. Are you suggesting I have to use the slave nic eth1?

Comment: I have no clue, but possibly MSFT docs was referring to eth1 when instructing to watch `vf_*` stats?

Comment: Your last statement gave me a clue. In the doc they were saying about eth0 not eth1. So I was posting the right outputs. I checked the slave interface on a standard debian system, and it was up. where as on my system its down. So I started it up and now I am getting some stats in vf_tx_packets and vf_tx_bytes but rx is still zero. I thing we are getting closer here.